# Hiding platform toolset in solution explorer for C++ projects

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 on a solution where all c++ projects have platform toolset of Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP. I cannot upgrade them for compatibility reasons with the rest of the developers. However, the string "(Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP)" is added to all project names in solution explorer and generates a lot of clutter in my eyes.

Is there any way to hide it? I know that all projects are of this platform. I don't need VS to tell me :)

Comment: No, you can stop looking, there is no option to hide that.  Use [uservoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) to add feature requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this. It involves editing some files that maybe shouldn't be edited, and it's likely unsupported and may mess up your installation, but as long as you back up the modified files you should be able to revert if anything bad happens. That's the warning.

That said, I've tried this and it worked for me without any issues (that I'm aware of) and I do believe the procedure is safe as it mainly relates to cosmetics (although it might break future upgrades).

If you installed VS2013 in the default location you should have a file called `Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props` in the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120`

This file contains, among other things, information on how (some of the) the installed platform toolsets are displayed in the project property pages and what string (if any) is added to the project name in the solution explorer.

The rows with properties called something like `_PlatformToolsetShortNameFor_v120_xp` control the string that is shown in the solution explorer (in this case the *2013 - xp toolset*), and the rows with properties called something like `_PlatformToolsetFriendlyNameFor_v120_xp` control what's shown in the project property page.

As the `Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)` toolset by default didn't show anything extra in the solution explorer I added a row for:

```
<_PlatformToolsetShortNameFor_v120_xp Condition="'$(_PlatformToolsetShortNameFor_v120_xp)' == ''">LOLZ I Changed This - Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)</_PlatformToolsetShortNameFor_v120_xp>
```

and also modified the `_PlatformToolsetFriendlyNameFor_v120_xp` like this:

```
<_PlatformToolsetFriendlyNameFor_v120_xp Condition="'$(_PlatformToolsetFriendlyNameFor_v120_xp)' == ''">OH MY - Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)</_PlatformToolsetFriendlyNameFor_v120_xp>
```

And the results were this:

[image]
and this:
[image]

To hide the string that gets appended to the project name in the solution explorer simply remove or comment out the corresponding `PlatformToolsetShortNameFor`. Since it's an xml-file you comment using `<!--` and `-->`

Comment: Note that if you're using VS2017, the corresponding file will be e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props`